# Writing the following mySQL request in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

Let me preface by saying I know nothing about doctrine, but at my new position we use it all over the place (not sure why...). Either way, here's the php and mySQL statement I'm trying to turn into a Doctrine statement:

```
$find_vac = mysql_query("SELECT Vacancies FROM States WHERE Abbreviation = '".$state."'");
```

I think the part that's tripping me up is where the Abbreviation is a variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

UPDATE:

```
$res = Doctrine_Query::create()
->select('Vacancies')
->from('States')
->where('Abbreviation = ?', $state)
->execute();
$vacancies = $res[0]->getVacancies();
```

The above returns an error.

```
echo $res['Vacancies']."<br />";
```

This returns the number 4 no matter which state is selected (and even then all states range from 0-3 for the number of vacancies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it. The variables can be inserted into the query in the same way as prepared statements.

```
$res = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('Vacancies')
    ->from('States')
    ->where('Abbreviation = ?', $state)
    ->execute();
```

**EDIT**: This will give you an array of `States` in array form that match the search criteria. If you just want to get the value of the first one's vacancies, you can get it like this:

```
$vacancies = $res[0]['Vacancies'];
```

Or course, you'll also want to check that `$res[0]` exists and is itself an array in case a bogus or nonexistent `$state` is used.

Comment: But the result of that I have no idea what to do with. It should be returning one number, and echoing that does not return what I'm expecting... How do I get it to give me the one number?

Comment: I've edited my answer, see if that helps you get the correct value.

Comment: The updated code is throwing an error... Here's a little more information. Obviously this is a list of states, the abbreviation is passed through by a form on another page, which is the $state variable. I need to find the number of vacancies for that state. I have no idea how doctrine is outputting this code. I tried: echo $res['Vacancies']; which results in the number 4 (for all states), which is incorrect.

Comment: Can you give some more information about the error, and maybe a a clip of the source code you have now?

Comment: Error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException' with message 'Unknown method States::getVacancies'
---
See above update for code used.

Comment: Okay, maybe `execute()` is returning the results as arrays and not objects as I remembered. Try `echo $res[0]['Vacancies']` and see if that gives correct results. If not, see what `var_dump($res)` gives you, that might be helpful.

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you SO much! You don't know how long I've been battling this horrid language (is it even a language? library?)!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! :) I'll update my answer to reflect the solution that worked.